# Which function is used for the prediction in Sparks Mllib

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

What function is used to calculate the prediction for a certain data point.  Consider the following code:

```
final LogisticRegressionModel model = logisticRegression.run(train.rdd());
point = train.rdd().take(0);
Double prediction = model.predict(point.features());
```

I thought is would be

[image]

but I could not find the documentation that implements this function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is using a standard logistic function (*y* in your formula is out of place):

[image]

which [is implemented as](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/a95252823e09939b654dd425db38dadc4100bc87/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/classification/LogisticRegression.scala#L123-L124):

```scala
val margin = dot(weightMatrix, dataMatrix) + intercept
val score = 1.0 / (1.0 + math.exp(-margin))
```

To obtain raw value you should `clearThreshold`.